# Toughbook CF-C2 touch screen not detected

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch, screen

I am trying to run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with my toughbook CF-C2. Windows is on the other partion and everything works fine there but when I am on ubuntu it does not detect that the screen is a touchscreen. Mabye its not compatible I dont know, any suggestions? 
Thanks for reading

http://www.panasonic.com/business/toughbook/semi-rugged-C2-convertible-tablet-pc.asp

Comment: I have same model and running ubuntu (14.04) on it. Touch screen works fine, like all other Toughbooks I have. Have you checked bios that touch screen is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

...I think on some Panasonic CF-C2 models (I have the CF-C2CCAZXCM model that comes also with a stylus), the USB id changed and it isn't recognized by the current wacom.ko kernel module . Below are the steps that I used to get the multi-touch, and the stylus working with Ubuntu 14.04 . Please note that these are from my own notes during the process, and may not be fully polished. Most of my sources online were from varied websites found via Google, but the most important website was probably:

- http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom (wiki on the input-wacom driver )

Anyway, I hope it helps someone out there.

```
- sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-source
- sudo apt-get build-dep xf86-input-wacom (optional ?)
- download input-wacom-0.23.0.tar.bz2
(http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/files/xf86-input-wacom/input-wacom/)
- tar -jvxf input-wacom-0.23.0.tar.bz2
- cd 3.7
- vi wacom_wac.c
(@line 2241)
static const struct wacom_features wacom_features_0x117 =
        { "Wacom ISDv4 117",      WACOM_PKGLEN_MTTPC,     26202, 16325,  255,
          0, MTTPC, WACOM_INTUOS_RES, WACOM_INTUOS_RES };
...
(@line 2471)         
{ USB_DEVICE_WACOM(0x117) },

:wq (save and quit)

- cd ..
- ./configure
- make
- sudo cp 3.7/wacom.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/input/tablet/.
- sudo vi /etc/modules
wacom (add this additional entry in /etc/modules) 

- sudo vi  /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-wacom.conf
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Wacom touch options"
        MatchDriver "wacom"
        MatchProduct "Finger"

        Option "TopX" "80"
        Option "TopY" "-111"
        Option "BottomX" "11067"
        Option "BottomY" "6170"
EndSection

- reboot
```

- reboot

Comment: These instructions will be kinda difficult for a person with no prior experience with Ubuntu to follow. I'm having a hard time myself. Can you please outline each and every step nicely like you're explaining to a six-year old.

Comment: yeah im trying to follow along but no luck