# Touchscreen not working on Toughbook CF-C2

Tags: touchscreen

I have a Panasonic Toughbook CF-C2CQAZXCM with the touchpad (NOT the touchpad+digitizer) and I cannot get the touchscreen to work. I followed [Toughbook CF-C2 touch screen not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484226/toughbook-cf-c2-touch-screen-not-detected?newreg=14fce1978c444a24bbfbe296b631b2b8) and was able to build the modules but no joy. I followed several other threads:

- http://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/support-requests/38/
- http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/touchscreen-info-or-ubuntu-drivers-for-toughbook-h2-field.637614/
- http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom

Here is some info from my system:

```
# xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB HD Webcam                             id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Panasonic Laptop Support                  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

```
# lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 5986:0529 Acer, Inc 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04b5:0680 ROHM LSI Systems USA, LLC 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 056a:5005 Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bc2:5021 Seagate RSS LLC FreeAgent GoFlex USB 2.0
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
...and in dmesg:
[    1.824466] usb 2-4: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.824571] usb 2-4: Device not responding to set address.
[    1.988164] psmouse serio2: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 7.5, id: 0x1c0b1, caps: 0xf00033/0x244000/0xa2400, board id: 372, fw id: 1107777
[    2.025355] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input9
[    2.028723] usb 2-4: Device not responding to set address.
[    2.232873] usb 2-4: device not accepting address 3, error -71
[    2.345062] usb 2-4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.361709] usb 2-4: No LPM exit latency info found.  Power management will be impacted.
[    2.362951] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=056a, idProduct=5005
[    2.362955] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[    2.362957] usb 2-4: Product: MultiTouch Sensor  
[    2.362959] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Wacom Co.,Ltd.      
[    2.362960] usb 2-4: SerialNumber:
```

Don't know where to go from here. The touchscreen works on boot when I enter the Panasonic Admin password but not after it loads Ubuntu. I did a fresh install of 14.04 LTS in case that made a difference.

Comments??

Comment: Was that your edit Phil?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it.

[How to get Bamboo Pad working on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530205/how-to-get-bamboo-pad-working-on-ubuntu-14-04/531188#531188)

I went as far as the first step - update grub. I did NOT have to alter /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-wacom.conf or build input-wacom. Everything works. I see:

```
xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Co.,Ltd.       MultiTouch Sensor   touch    id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB HD Webcam                             id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Panasonic Laptop Support                  id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Now I can play around with the multi-touch stuff, but I'm happy to have basic touch.